# CentOS7 found wifi device use lsmod but nmcli

Tags: centos, wifi

I could find my wireless device (rtl8188eu) using the command `lsmod` after updating the kernel to version 4.10 in CentOS 7

```
# uname -r
4.10.2-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

# lsmod | grep 8188
r8188eu               425984  0
cfg80211              593920  1 r8188eu
```

But I couldn't find it using `nmcli` or connect to my AP

```
# nmcli d
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
virbr0      bridge    connected  virbr0     
enp0s25     ethernet  connected  enp0s25    
lo          loopback  unmanaged  --         
virbr0-nic  tun       unmanaged  --
```

How can I solve this problem?

############## following update 20170317

output of command "ip link", device can be found:

`# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:97:0e:c1:72:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp0s26u1u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:5a:39:d0:5f:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:dd:7c:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:dd:7c:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

output of command "iw dev", it seems something wrong:

`# iw dev
nl80211 not found.`

output of command "dmesg" what about 8188eu:

`[    7.254757] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.256024] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
[    7.301472] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[    7.335032] 8188eu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.336670] Error: Driver 'r8188eu' is already registered, aborting...
[    7.364792] r8188eu 1-1.2:1.0 wlp0s26u1u2: renamed from wlan0`

my adapter is usb device, so lspci -n nothing found.

output of command "lsusb"

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter`

output of command "journalctl":

`# journalctl | grep 8188
Mar 17 08:00:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
Mar 17 08:00:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
Mar 17 08:00:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
Mar 17 08:00:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: 8188eu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Mar 17 08:00:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: Error: Driver 'r8188eu' is already registered, aborting...
Mar 17 08:00:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: r8188eu 1-1.2:1.0 wlp0s26u1u2: renamed from wlan0`

Comment: Look at all intermediate levels: Output of `ip link`? Outout of `iw dev`? What are the messages in `dmesg` wrt. your WLAN device? Any error messages? How exactly does the WLAN device identify itself (`lspci -n` or `lsusb`, whatever appropriate)?

Comment: The `lsmod` command only shows loaded kernel modules by formatting the contents of /proc/modules. If the module for your wireless device is loaded automatically, it means the kernel detected it. Check `dmesg` and `journalctl` for errors.

Comment: @dirkt I was post output of commands, it seems message "nl80211 not found" make something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the output of the commands, you do have a WLAN interface called `wlp0s26u1u2`, which is currently `DOWN` (not active). You also got a clear warning that the driver is in the staging state (an early attempt), so it is not expect to work correctly. You also got an error message

```
Error: Driver 'r8188eu' is already registered, aborting...
```

which means that during initialization of the driver something goes wrong, and it aborts the operation. Though the message is somewhat strange, unless you are really trying to load the driver twice for some reason...

Unless you can debug kernel code (which you probably can't), you don't have much chance to get that working. The only thing you can do is to upgrade to the newest kernel (if necessary, get sources and compile one yourself), cross your fingers and hope that someone fixed this problem.